# The date is incorrectly truncated if the action was conversion to comment

Tags: bug, convert-to-comment

Just noticed in [this deleted answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7514/how-do-i-eat-from-a-bowl-without-needing-to-clean-it/7518#7518).

[image]

The date "X mins/hours/whatever ago" should be fully moved to the new line.